# changing css properties on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to change css properties of my website on click, more specifically the navbar at the moment then hoping to expand later.
currently i have this.

```
 <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Page 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu1">
                    <li id="greenBg"><a href="#" onclick="changeNavbarColor()">Makes the navbar green </a></li>
                    <li id="orangeBg"><a href="#" onclick="changeNavbarColor()">Makes the navbar orange </a></li>
                    <li id="blueBg"><a href="#" onclick="changeNavbarColor()">Makes the navbar blue </a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>

function changeNavbarColor(){

    var navbarCol = document.getElementById("container-fluid1");
    var greenBg = document.getElementById("greenBg");
    var orangeBg = document.getElementById("orangeBg");
    var blueBg = document.getElementById("blueBg");
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown-menu1");


    var blue = #06F;
    var green = #060;
    var orange = #F60;

    if(dropdown.id == "greenBg"){
        greenBg.style.backgroundColor = green;
    }else if(dropdown.id == "blueBg"){
        blueBg.style.backgroundColor = blue;
    }else if(dropdown.id == "orangeBg"){
        orangeBg.style.backgroundColor = orange;
    };


}
```

was hoping that everytime one of the links is clicked then it would change to that color. so far nothing happening. maybe something to do with access the element where i have dropdown.id

thanks

Comment: Your `dropdown.id` will never be one of the values, because the id is `dropdown-menu1`

Comment: but i have set dropdown as a variable that searches for dropdown-menu1?

Comment: You have set the variable (`dropdown`) to the element with the id `dropdown-menu1` and only to this element. So, in the next step you are looking for the `id` of this particular element and this will be consequently `dropdown-menu1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this; Slightly modified from your code

```
 <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Page 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu1">
                    <li id="greenBg"><a onclick="changeNavbarColor('greenBg')">Makes the navbar green </a></li>
                    <li id="orangeBg"><a href="#" onclick="changeNavbarColor('orangeBg')">Makes the navbar orange </a></li>
                    <li id="blueBg"><a href="#" onclick="changeNavbarColor('blueBg')">Makes the navbar blue </a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>

function changeNavbarColor(ids){

var navbarCol = document.getElementById("container-fluid1");
var greenBg = document.getElementById("greenBg");
var orangeBg = document.getElementById("orangeBg");
var blueBg = document.getElementById("blueBg");
var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown-menu1");

var blue = "#06F";
var green = "#060";
var orange = "#F60";

if(ids == "greenBg"){
    greenBg.style.backgroundColor = green;
}else if(ids == "blueBg"){
    blueBg.style.backgroundColor = blue;
}else if(ids== "orangeBg"){
    orangeBg.style.backgroundColor = orange;
};
```

}

Comment: this works! thanks my man

Answer (score 2):

You are not selecting the right element we can solve that by injecting `this` in the `onlick` handler.

You need to pass in the context for the object clicked width `event.target` so we can take the parent element then check the id of it since the object clicked will be a `anchor` element so so get the id we do `event.target.parentNode.id`

Html:

```
<li id="greenBg"><a href="#" onclick="changeNavbarColor(this)">Makes the navbar green </a></li>
```

We need to pass in this as the context so we can get the target

JS:

```
if(event.target.parentNode.id == "greenBg"){
      greenBg.style.backgroundColor = green;
  }
```

Here we finally check the right id of the clicked element and change the background.

You also have to set the colors as a string like this `var blue = "#06F";` or else you will get a error since its looking for a variable.

You can see the working example [here](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/dYpEwG?editors=101)

Answer (score -3):

If you can use jQuery, try this code:

```
$('#dropdown-menu1 li').on('click', function(){

    var bg;
    if($(this).attr('id') == "greenBg"){
       bg = 'green';
    }else if($(this).attr('id') == "blueBg"){
       bg = 'blue';
    }else if($(this).attr('id') == "orangeBg"){
       bg = 'orange';
    };

    $(this).css("background-color", bg );
});
```

But this is not the best way to code. It is better to add custom attribute to your li element, for example:

```
 <li id="greenBg" data-color="green"><a href="#">Makes the navbar green </a></li>
```

Then you can use this short code:

```
 $(this).css("background-color", $(this).data("color") );
```

Here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/x86esu6j/ 
I cannot understand why the author should use "html onclick" instead of event listener.

Comment: Remove `a` in selector.. This will work then.. because `id` is set to `li` not `a`

Comment: it's close without the a as guruprasad rao said. but it changes the colour of the background of the links instead of the actual navbar

Comment: your latest solution is doing the same as the above where it is making the dropdown background turn the respective colour but not the navbar

Comment: And why does one need to involve a JS library here?

Comment: Obese Octopus already uses Bootstrap Dropdown so why not to use jquery if it already loaded?